# Suppose that $f$ is continuous, $f(x) \geq 0$ on $[a, b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = 0.$ Show that $f(x) = 0$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f$ is continuous, $f(x) \geq 0$ on $[a, b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = 0.$ Show that $f(x) = 0$ on $[a,b]$.
I started by concluding that $F(a) = F(b)$ and by lagrange-theorem there exists $c \in [a,b]$ s.t $F'(c) = f(c) = 0$. And then I assumed that there exists $x_{0} \in [a,b]$ s.t $f(x_{0}) > 0$. And that means that there exists $\delta > 0$ s.t $f(x) \geq \frac{f(x_{0})}{2}$ for every $\lvert x - x_{0} \rvert < \delta$. And then I showed that $f(c) = 0 \geq \frac{f(x_{0})}{2} > 0$ which is a contradiction. 
But who assures me that $\lvert c - x_{0} \rvert < \delta$ ?

What is a better way to solve this? Am I even close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, you can assume that $(x_0-\delta,x_0)\subset[a,b]$. Then$\int_a^bf(x)dx\geq\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0}f(x)dx\geq\delta\cdot\frac{f(x_0)}{2}>0$. Contradiction!

Comment: From the view of real analysis, $f(x)$ is not $0$ only in a set of measure zero. But it is not $0$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you have $f(x) \ge \frac{f(x_0)}{2}$ on the interval $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$ then (assuming that $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \subset (a, b)$ ) you get 
$$
f \ge \frac{f(x_0)}{2}\chi_{(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)} \qquad \text{on } [a,b].
$$
Therefore
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx \ge \int_a^b \frac{f(x_0)}{2}\chi_{(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)} (x) dx = \delta f(x_0) > 0 . $$
And this is a contraddiction.

EDIT: If $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$ you have to intersect it with $[a,b]$ and the intersection has still a positive length.